# Referencing pivot tables from excel 2012 in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on a macro right now that references a pivot table but the problem I'm having is that my reference is only for a specific cell range and I can't get it to reference the entire table as it grows or shrinks depending on the data. I've tried a few different things but I have no experience with VB so I'm not sure I entirely understand the syntax...

This is what I have currently:

```
Sheets("Loader").Select
Range("C11").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Sheets("Worksheet").Select
Range("U4:Y10").Select
Selection.Copy
```

The "U4:Y10" reference should be the information within the pivot table

Comment: Any time you are wondering how to do something in an Excel macro, you might consider recording it as a macro, which allows Excel to write the code for you.  You can then go back and edit it to suit your needs.  This is sometimes much easier than hunting in a reference manual.

Comment: Thats what I ended up doing.. Thank you very much though, that did make it easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Range.PivotTable.x for the Range of the values within the pivot table where x is a choice from the valid ranges shown in my example below.

E.g. in your case use Cell U4 as the anchor cell from which to find the Pivot Table that contains it: Debug.Print Range("U4").PivotTable.TableRange1.Address (prints e.g. "U4:Y30")

The various choices over which range you want are such as:

```
With Range("U4").PivotTable
    .DataBodyRange 'Range of just the values
    .ColumnRange 'Range of Column 'labels'
    .RowRange 'Range of Row 'labels'
    .TableRange1 'Range of entire table (excluding page fields)
    .TableRange2 'Range of entire table (including page fields)
End With
```

Comment: Not really sure, I don't have much experience with this so I'm kind of just playing it by ear.. I tried what you're saying but it gave me the Invalid use of property error

Comment: I put it in exactly as you have it written. Then copied and pasted it to another worksheet. Nothing too complicated. Am I missing a reference?

Comment: @JimmyLive what I have written is an example and returns a range object. A range object cannot be used as a statement. Add whatever you want to do with the range object after it. (like ".Select")

Comment: Alright I see what you're saying now. I'm getting different numbers on my final answer now but I'm sure that I can fiddle with it and figure out whats getting messed up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JimmyLive see my edited answer: I have added in the various choices for which range you want (like values only, column headers only, row headers only, entire pivot table etc)