# Referencing Pivot Table data using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, reference, pivot-table

I'm trying to list **row labels** of a pivot table but can't access them. They don't show up as row labels so I am not sure.

**Example:**

```
Row Labels     Sum of Resources
----------     ----------------
 item 1             1
 item 2             4
 item 3             2
```

I want to be able to access `item1`, `item2`, and `item3`.

The code I have so far is below and it does what I want *except* for access items 1 to 3:

```
Dim item As Variant
For Each item In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot1"). _
                             PivotFields("Sum of Resource").DataRange
    Debug.Print item;
Next item
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [VBA - Select Cells from Pivot Table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18318862/8112776) and/or [Referencing pivot tables from excel 2012 in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18188901/8112776). See also, a good resource here: [**Referencing Pivot Table Ranges in VBA**](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/) plus documentation on [the **`GetPivotData` method**](//msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-getpivotdata-method-excel).

Comment: *Welcome to [so]!* Below are some links with tips to get you started with [so]'s posting guidelines. See the **[help/on-topic]** and tips about research [*here*](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592). It's helpful to include a **[mcve]** plus some **background info** as there are often alternate methods to accomplish a task. More quick-but-recommended reads: "[ask]" as well as the [**tips here**](//codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/). Good Luck!

Comment: I know how to acces pivot table range but I cant access the row labels.

Comment: Although a solution likely lies within the links to similar/duplicate questions (above) I am curious as to ***why*** you want to look at the Pivot Table labels, because there's likely a better way of accomplishing what you're trying to do.  For example, if the Pivot Table is grouping and sorting by the most occurrences of a certain value, and you want the top 3 from the list, there are basic worksheet formulas that would return the same values without relying on a flakey reference to a pivot table whose shape might change unexpectedly.

Comment: Each row label is a branch in our department. I want to find which branch has the highest value in resources and list the branches based on there values.

Comment: I don't want to access them the range directly in case the number of branches change

Comment: There are more options in my [edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51471579/8112776) (below),  and several others possibilities a few clicks away. Hopefully I provided enough information to get you started towards finding a suitable solution.  "Next time", note that more specific information including background and representative examples in your question would be helpful in quickly finding a specific solution (as per the links in [my 2nd comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8112776/ashleedawg), above.  And again, welcome to [so]!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Refer directly to the cell

Further to our [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51471390/referencing-pivot-table-data-using-vba/51471579#comment89911301_51471390), this is *not* the best way to get a summary of data, but you seem determined, and without more information about what you have and what you're trying to do, I can only wonder why you don't just refer to the label cells ***"like any other cell"***.

**Example:**

[image: img]

- In the example above, `=D2` returns `A`, which is the first label of the PivotTable.

---

### The `GetPivotData` setting & functions

**Note** that your formulas with the above examlpe might appear differently depending on your settings (in Options) for *"`Use GetPivotData functions for PivotTable references`"* (mine is unselected), but the end result is the same either way.

[image: img]
<sup>Click image to enlarge.</sup>

- There is more information about `GetPivotData` in the [documentation **here**](https://support.office.com/article/getpivotdata-function-8c083b99-a922-4ca0-af5e-3af55960761f).

---

### The `DataLabelRange` property

There are several other ways of referring to [any] part of a PivotTable, some more reliable than others if the data is changing often.  An alternative could be to use **the `DataLabelRange` property**.

- More on the `DataLabelRange` property in the [documentation **here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/vba/excel-vba/articles/pivottable-datalabelrange-property-excel) and [examples **here**](https://peltiertech.com/referencing-pivot-table-ranges-in-vba/).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out how to do this. Not sure if anyone else has this issue but the code below will list all the row labels.

```
'Get Row labels
For Each item In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot-Table").RowRange
    If Not count = 0 And Not count = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot-Table").RowRange.count - 1 Then
        Debug.Print item
    End If
    count = count + 1
Next item
```

This code will print all row labels ignoraing the grand total and row label caption